# Specify NaN encoding in np.where() logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I have data that looks like this:

```
    id    case2_q6
0   300   3.0
1   304   4.0
2   306   3.0
3   309   1.0
4   311   3.0
5   312   4.0
6   314   NaN
7   315   2.0
8   316   3.0
9   317   3.0
```

And using this `np.where()` function call to generate new variables:

```
df['fluid_2'] = np.where((df['case2_q6'] == 1) | (df['case2_q6'] == 2), 1, 0)
```

Now `df` has the column `fluid_2` as below:

```
    id    case2_q6  fluid_2
0   300   3.0       0
1   304   4.0       0
2   306   3.0       0
3   309   1.0       1
4   311   3.0       0
5   312   4.0       0
6   314   NaN       0
7   315   2.0       1
8   316   3.0       0
9   317   3.0       0
```

As you can see, the `NaN` value at index `6` was converted to a 0. Is there a way to set up the `np.where()` so as to leave those as NaN values in `fluid_2`?

The desired output would be:

```
    id    case2_q6  fluid_2
0   300   3.0       0
1   304   4.0       0
2   306   3.0       0
3   309   1.0       1
4   311   3.0       0
5   312   4.0       0
6   314   NaN       NaN
7   315   2.0       1
8   316   3.0       0
9   317   3.0       0
```

Where the `NaN` is preserved.

Comment: So you want a choice among 3 values, 0, 1, nan.  A single `where` isn't enough, since it is a two-way chooser.

Comment: Agreed. The accepted solution takes this into account.

Comment: `df['case_q6'].isin([1,2]).astype(int).where(df['case_q6'].notna())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df['fluid_2'] = np.where(
    df['case2_q6'].isna(), np.nan, 
    np.where((df['case2_q6'] == 1) | (df['case2_q6'] == 2), 1, 0))
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
df['fluid_2'] = df['case2_q6'].clip(upper=1).mul(df['case2_q6'].isin([1,2]))
```

---

Output:

```
    id  case2_q6  fluid_2
0  300       3.0      0.0
1  304       4.0      0.0
2  306       3.0      0.0
3  309       1.0      1.0
4  311       3.0      0.0
5  312       4.0      0.0
6  314       NaN      NaN
7  315       2.0      1.0
8  316       3.0      0.0
9  317       3.0      0.0
```

Comment: Ok, cool. So basically this is saying if `case2_q6` is `NaN`, set it to `NaN`, and maintain the rest of the original logic?

Comment: Exactly, @hulio_entredas!

Comment: Got it, thank you! That's pretty intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Lets drop the null values and use `isin` to check for the condition

```
df['fluid_2'] = df['case2_q6'].dropna().isin([1, 2]).astype('int')
```

---

```
     id  case2_q6  fluid_2
0  300       3.0      0.0
1  304       4.0      0.0
2  306       3.0      0.0
3  309       1.0      1.0
4  311       3.0      0.0
5  312       4.0      0.0
6  314       NaN      NaN
7  315       2.0      1.0
8  316       3.0      0.0
9  317       3.0      0.0
```

Comment: Interesting, but not as intuitive (to me at least) as PaulS's answer.